# Unable to start elastic search in RHEL 7

Tags: elasticsearch, java-8, rhel7

I have installed JDK and also elastic search 1.4.5.

when I tried to start it using 'sudo systemctl start elasticsearch.service'
I faced the below error.

```
elasticsearch.service - Starts and stops a single elasticsearch instance on this system
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2015-09-10 09:51:13 EDT; 8s ago
     Docs: http://www.elasticsearch.org
  Process: 2456 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -d -p /var/run/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.pid -Des.default.config=$CONF_FILE -Des.default.path.home=$ES_HOME -Des.default.path.logs=$LOG_DIR -Des.default.path.data=$DATA_DIR -Des.default.path.work=$WORK_DIR -Des.default.path.conf=$CONF_DIR (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Can you please help me through this?

Comment: Same here, any solutions?

Comment: It didn't work for me, so I just tried to install higher version of elastic search  say version 1.7 rpm package. I can able to get it !!

Comment: I solved it, in my case it was a problem with the Java version because I upgraded to the oracle 8u60 and had to configure the JVM memory properly.